# Searching in XML file - PHP

Tags: php, xml

My XML looks like this

```
<root lastUpdated="20180101120330" ttl="24">
<Parent1>...</Parent1>
<Parent2>
<sub parm1="google.com" parm2="email@email.com" parm3="5343243434" parm4="google" parm5="876787" parm6="" parm7="ACTIVE">...</sub>
<sub parm1="yahoo.com" parm2="email2@email.com" parm3="4434343" parm4="yahoo" parm5="232322" parm6="" parm7="ACTIVE">...</sub>
<sub parm1="facebook.com" parm2="email3@email.com" parm3="222334" parm4="facebook" parm5="12233" parm6="" parm7="ACTIVE">...</sub>
</Parent2>
</root>
```

I want to look for parm3 and if it matches it should return parm1.
XML is stored in local directory.

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking here? Maybe do a search for "how to read XML with PHP" or something.

Comment: Use xpath `//sub[@parm3="4434343"]/@parm1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and use an xpath query like `/root/Parent2/sub` for the `<sub>` items in `<Parent2>`.

Or for example `/root/*[starts-with(name(),'Parent')]/sub` for the `<sub>` elements in the `<Parent...>` elements.

You could then make your comparison using the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

```
$data = <<<DATA
<root lastUpdated="20180101120330" ttl="24">
    <Parent1></Parent1>
    <Parent2>
        <sub parm1="google.com" parm2="email@email.com" parm3="5343243434" parm4="google" parm5="876787" parm6="" parm7="ACTIVE">...</sub>
        <sub parm1="yahoo.com" parm2="email2@email.com" parm3="4434343" parm4="yahoo" parm5="232322" parm6="" parm7="ACTIVE">...</sub>
        <sub parm1="facebook.com" parm2="email3@email.com" parm3="222334" parm4="facebook" parm5="12233" parm6="" parm7="ACTIVE">...</sub>
    </Parent2>
</root>
DATA;


$elm= new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$a = $elm->xpath('/root/Parent2/sub');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    if ((string)$a[$i]->attributes()->parm3 === "4434343") {
        echo $a[$i]->attributes()->parm1;
    }
}
```

[Output 1](https://3v4l.org/FPvtW)
[Output 2](https://3v4l.org/Up3CS)